# Loading Mathematica 4 optimized package in Mathematica 10

Tags: packages, compatibility

I have a Mathematica package that is optimised for *Mathematica 4.0*, but the version I'm using is *10.1*. Whenever I load this package, I'm getting error messages like `` Get::noopen: Cannot open Statistics`LinearRegression` ``, etc. Is there a way by which I could run this older package, without changing the code?

Comment: "Is there a way by which I could run this older package, without changing the code?".  No, the only way to run it in a more recent version is to update the code.  I think ``Statistics`LinearRegression` `` may have moved to ``LinearRegression` ``, but even that package is considered obsolete.  Almost certainly, several other modifications will be necessary to run suh old code.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way by which I could run this older package, without changing the code?

**No, the only way to run it in a more recent version is to update the code.**

I think `` Statistics`LinearRegression` `` may have moved to `` LinearRegression` ``, but even that package is considered obsolete.  Almost certainly, several other modifications will be necessary to run such old code.  The nature of the required modifications will be specific to each application, so it is impossible to say more.

[This guide on incompatible changes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html) is useful because it discusses some of the deep-reaching changes to the graphics systems that happened in version 6. But it only goes up to version 7. Lots of things have changed between v7 and v10.

---

Mathematica has decent cross-version compatibility, but keep in mind that version 4.0 was released 18 years ago.  Even so, most non-graphics-related changes should be straightforward.  The main source of incompatibilities is typically name conflicts between symbols in the old package and built-in symbols that were introduced at a later time.

Comment: Actually one can find the compatibility information of `Statistics\`LinearRegression\`` by searching it in the document: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Statistics/LinearRegression.html